# prestashop: get final product category

Tags: php, sql

In general, in [Prestashop](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/) there are no functions to really have the final category (i.e. the one with highest *level_depth*) of a product based on id_product, so I extended the Product class and added this simple static method:

```
public static function get_product_category($id_product, $id_lang = null){
    $lang = (!isset($id_lang)) ? (int)Context::getContext()->language->id : $id_lang;

    $db = Db::getInstance();

    $sql = 'SELECT
                    c.id_category,
                    c.id_parent,
                    cl.name,
                    cl.link_rewrite

              FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product cp
              INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category c ON cp.id_category = c.id_category
              INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang cl ON cl.id_category = c.id_category
              WHERE cp.id_product = ' . bqSQL($id_product) . ' and cl.id_lang = ' . bqSQL($lang) . '
              ORDER BY c.level_depth DESC
              LIMIT 1';

    $result = $db->ExecuteS($sql);

    return $result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind this code was posted more than a few years ago, perhaps it has changed dramatically since then. Hopefully the suggestions below will still be relevant and helpful.

This code looks okay - not difficult to read. I haven't used Prestashop before but it appears that the [`bqSQL()` function mitigates SQL injection attacks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/database/db/#db-class-methods). I'm not sure if the Prestashop DB class has support for bound parameters but that would also be a good technique for avoiding SQL injection.

It would be good to consider following a style guide like [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/), which replaced [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

> #### 4.4 Methods and Functions
>
> Method and function names MUST NOT be declared with space after the method name. The opening brace MUST go on its own line, and the closing brace MUST go on the next line following the body.

I notice the opening brace on the method is on the same line, which I am used to having worked with code like that in the past decade but I would recommend at least adding a space between the closing parenthesis of the parameters and the opening brace.

> ```
> ...$id_lang = null){
> ```

If the code is now running on PHP 7+ then [a return type declaration could be added](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations). In that case it may be advantageous to have the opening brace on its own line  - e.g.

```
public static function get_product_category($id_product, $id_lang = null): array 
{
```